# Apply lambda function to columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I have [a google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HkjwgMxp5i_URalgz8w5YswniNMfPX2S6UZ0QUoka8/edit?usp=sharing) where certain answers are not in the right place.

Indeed, I would like that, for each line, given the answer in the last column, if the answer is not already in an Answeri column, we move this answer to the left in the first column which is none.

That is to say get a thing like:

```
    Questions   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4    Answer6
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   'Not preferred'     2   3   4   'Preferred'    None
58  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   'Low affected'  2   3   4    5    'High affected'
```

So far I've written this:

```
import pandas as pd

def put_at_right_place(row):
    if row.Answer257 not in [None, np.nan]:
        answer = row.Answer257
        if answer not in row.Answer0:
            for i in range(0,257):
                # on choppe la premiere colonne qui n'est pas None
                if row[f'Answer{i}']== None:
                    index_to_replace = 'Answer' + str(i-1)
                    row[index_to_replace] = row.Answer257

df = pd.read_csv('la_hoja_del_vinclulo.csv')
df.apply(lambda x: put_at_right_place(x), axis=1)
```

As it is in the Google sheets, I will be very happy to try the Javascript Editor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since I take it the ultimate goal is to actually analyse the data...;)

I would melt your df:

```
unique_cols = ["QID_x","URL_x","Questions", 
               "Answers_x","Section","QType_x",
               "Theme","Topics"]
results = df.melt(id_vars=unique_cols, 
                  var_name="Answer", 
                  value_name="Value")
results = results[pd.notnull(results["Value"])]
```

You can now easily analyse each question:

```
results[results.QID_x == 1]
```

After you melted you can then pivot back and do something like this:

```
results.sort_values(by='Answer').pivot(index="QID_x", columns='Answer', values='Value')
```

Then rejoin (pd.merge) with the initial frame (without the answers).

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the ultimate goal is not  to actually analyse the data, the goal is trying to move the answers from the last column on the right to the first column which is not None on their left in the dataframe.